# How to copy folders with same names recursively to another folder in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, shutil, copytree

- I have 10 folds, with 2 folders in each fold `face`, and `background`, I want to copy different folds inside train, validate folders so the train or validate will have `face`, `background` from different folds.
- I tried the following code, but since **Google Colab** uses **python 3.6.9**, I can't ignore the error of folder exists (as in **python 3.9**) so I get the following error:

### Error:

```py
try:
     mkdir(name, mode)
except OSError:
     # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'train/'
```

### My Code:

```py
#--------------
# Split Dataset
#==============
# we Already have the test set
# !mkdir train
# !mkdir valid
import os, shutil

fileList = os.listdir("NewDataset")
fileList.sort()
for i in [x for x in range(10) if ((x != 9) and (x != 1))]:
    # print(fileList[i])
    # Train
    if(i < 7):
        subPathList = glob.glob('NewDataset/'+fileList[i]+'/**/', recursive=False)
        for subPath in subPathList:
            shutil.copytree(subPath, 'train/')

    # Validate
    else:
        subPathList = glob.glob('NewDataset/'+fileList[i]+'/**/', recursive=False)
        for subPath in subPathList:
            shutil.copytree(subPath, 'valid/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to copy the files one by one recursively:

```py
import os, shutil

for i in [x for x in range(10) if ((x != 9) and (x != 1))]:
    # print(fileList[i])
    # Train
    if(i > 2):
        subPathList = glob.glob('/content/NewDataset/'+fileList[i]+'/**/', recursive=False)
        for subPath in subPathList:
            for im in os.listdir(subPath):
                imFullPath = os.path.join(subPath, im)
                targetPath = os.path.join('/content/train',subPath.split('/')[-2]+ '/')
                # print('Train: ', targetPath)
                shutil.copy(imFullPath, targetPath)
    # Validate
    else:
        subPathList = glob.glob('/content/NewDataset/'+fileList[i]+'/**/', recursive=False)
        for subPath in subPathList:
            for im in os.listdir(subPath):
                imFullPath = os.path.join(subPath, im)
                targetPath = os.path.join('/content/valid',subPath.split('/')[-2] + '/')
                # print('Validate: ', targetPath)
                shutil.copy(imFullPath, targetPath)
```